# How to access mounted file from the application hosted on same EKS pod

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, mount, fileshare

We have one c# application hosted on EKS cluster which is having two pods in linux OS.

We have a windows file share which needs to be accessed from the hosted application so we mounted the windows shared path using below commands.

```
mount -t cifs -o username=xxx,password=xxx //serverIP/ROOT/SharedFolderName /mnt
```

it mount the folder to the pods but when we try to access the file from the hosted application using
File.`Exists(\\mnt\shared\textfile.txt)`, ***it is not giving any response.***

Any help would be saviour for me.